# Sequentially rotate object along two arbitrary axes

Tags: animation

I'm trying to rotate an object around one (arbitrary) axis using a child of constraint. Next, I want to 'let go' (i.e. set influence to zero), rotate the object along the global Z axis then 'grab' (i.e. set influence to 1), and rotate the object a second time along the same axis used in the first rotation. I've tried adding empties and also experimented with visual transform, but can't seem to get it sorted out.

What am I missing?

Best regards,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out...:

- frame 1:

  - use 'child of' constraint to parent **object** to 1. axis (other object or empty)
- frame 60:

  - rotate axis 1
  - keyframe **object**'s rot/loc
- frame 61:

  - apply visual transform to **object**
  - keyframe constraint factor (1. axis) to 0
  - keyframe **object**'s rot/loc
  - add 'child of' constraint to **object** with 2. axis (other object or empty) as target
- frame 120:

  - rotate axis 2
  - keyframe **object**'s rot/loc
- frame 121:

  - apply visual transform to **object**
  - keyframe constraint factor (2. axis) to 0
  - keyframe **object**'s rot/loc
  - add 'child of' constraint to **object** with 1. axis as target
- frame 180:

  - rotate axis 1
  - etc.